# How to set the threshold of hashtable to avoid rehashing frequently?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In the second version of the Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C,about hashtable ,there is an exercise which says that in chain hashing if we go on many deletions,we will make the table sparse,which wastes much space.So we can rehash with a smaller table whose size is the half of the orginal one.Meanwhile if the table size is N and the number of elements is about 2N,we need to rehash a larger table.The question is before we rehash a smaller table, how sparse the table may be.

Below is the anwser:

We must be careful not to rehash too often. Let p be the threshold (fraction of table size) at
which we rehash to a smaller table. Then if the new table has size N, it contains 2pN elements. This table will require rehashing after either 2N − 2pN insertions or pN deletions.
Balancing these costs suggests that a good choice is p = 2/ 3.

For instance, suppose we have a table of size 300. If we rehash at 200 elements, then the new table size is N = 150,and we can do either 100 insertions or 100 deletions until a new rehash is required.
If we know that insertions are more frequent than deletions, then we might choose p to be
somewhat larger. If p is too close to 1.0, however, then a sequence of a small number of
deletions followed by insertions can cause frequent rehashing. In the worst case, if p = 1.0,
then alternating deletions and insertions both require rehashing.

I know how to get the value of p,but I can not understand why the answer thinks the elements is 2pN,I think this is just one of those all conditions,or does it have relationship with the chain hashing?Thanks for help.

Comment: If you resize the table when it has pN elements, and resizing takes N -> N/2, then you end up with 2pN elements.  Same elements.  Smaller N.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Oh my god! I have thought it over for half an hour but I never considered about the variable.You are so intelligent.Thanks a lot.